# wp_nav_menu only show the first 5 menu items

Tags: wordpress

How do I limit the number of menu items pulled in by wp_nav_menu? I only want to pull in the first 5 menu items even though there are 20 in the actual menu. The client will select the order and in all other places it's fine to have the full menu appear.

Here's what I'm trying but it doesn't seem to work :'-(

> wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'quicklinks', 'menu_item_start' => 1, 'menu_item_end' => 5) );

Answer (score 1):

Could you create a seperate menu in admin, with just those five items, in the order that the client wants them? Then you could attatch that menu to this location, and the other to the others.

Comment: That's an option, yes. That requires double entry and updating though.  It's my last resort. Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't normally advise duplication, but sometimes the alternative is even more complex. Hopefully someone else will have abetter answer.

Comment: @campatsky you could use [custom menu walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function).

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution which works (you need to modify "primary_navigation"):

```
function max_nav_items($sorted_menu_items, $args){
    if($args->theme_location != "primary_navigation") return $sorted_menu_items;
    $items = array();
    foreach($sorted_menu_items as $item){
        if($item->menu_item_parent != 0) continue;
        $items[] = $item;
    }
    $items = array_slice($items,0,8);
    foreach($sorted_menu_items as $key=>$one_item){
        if($one_item->menu_item_parent == 0 && !in_array($one_item,$items)){
            unset($sorted_menu_items[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $sorted_menu_items;
}
add_filter("wp_nav_menu_objects","max_nav_items",10,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) , in your case that would be `(n+6)`

```
nav.main-navigation li:nth-child(n+6){
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to your theme's functions.php file.

```
function limit_quicklinks_menu_items( $items, $args ) {
        if ( $args->theme_location == 'quicklinks' ) {
            $items = array_slice( $items, 0, 5 );
        }
        return $items;
    }

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'limit_quicklinks_menu_items', 10, 2 );
```

This code can be used to limit the number of menu items pulled in by wp_nav_menu() for a specific menu location, such as quicklinks. The code uses the wp_nav_menu_items filter to modify the menu items array before it's displayed.